# Expression Trees & Linq2Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, tree, expression

In the Linq2Sql query below could someone tell me

**1)** When is the sql query sent to sql server?

**a)** When query has the expression assigned to it or

**b)** (deferred execution) when it is required in the foreach loop?

```
var query = from c in myDataContext.Customers
            where c.FirstName == 'Tom'
            select c;

foreach(customer cust in query)
{
  //...do something
}
```

**2)** Does the .NET application or SQL Server convert the expression tree into a SQL query? The reason I ask this is because

**a)** All the reading I've done on expression trees says that they were needed in order to send code across the wire to be executed dynamically instead of sending MSIL.

**b)** If I hover over **query** after the expression is assigned to it, I can already see it has changed it to SQL

If the .NET application does the conversion then how can it really be said that an expression tree was sent over the wire to sql server? It just sent the sql string.

Answer (score 2):

1. The query is sent to the database whenever it absolutely has to be - usually when you start actually *requesting* data.

   In other words, it'll *probably* be either the call to `GetEnumerator()` or the first call to `IEnumerator<T>.MoveNext()`.
2. The C# compiler converts the lambda expression into IL which produces the expression tree object at execution time. LINQ to SQL then converts that expression tree to SQL to send to the database.

Expression trees are needed for LINQ to SQL in order to have a "data" representation of your code so that it can be converted to SQL at execution time. It's still SQL which is sent over the wire, but expression trees are required to create that SQL.

There are lots of blog posts on this sort of thing, including [this one by me](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/20/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-43-out-of-process-queries-with-iqueryable.aspx) a while ago.

Comment: re:1) Ok gotcha, so my example did not require anything to be evaluated so the execution was deferred until the foreach invoked the IEnumerator<T>.MoveNext() but if my query had a .Count in it then the query would have executed immediately.                                                         re:2) If the process is as you outline, how can it be said that the expression tree is sent across the wire? Everything is evaluated on the application side and converted to SQL which is then sent to the database to execute.

Comment: @FuzzyFrog: The expression tree *isn't* sent across the wire (for LINQ to SQL at least) - where did you read that it is? Note that "expression trees were needed in order to send code across the wire" isn't the same as saying "expression trees are sent across the wire". In LINQ to SQL, the SQL *is* the code after translation.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I think your note has nailed where my understanding was falling down in this matter. So would it be fair to say that expression trees really are just a handy way of storing a query expression that can be be traversed when needed and evaluated. L2S makes use of them because it has this deferred execution type behaviour.

Comment: @FuzzyFrog: No, it's not because of deferred execution really - it's because it needs to translate the source code into SQL. For that, it needs a representation *in data* of your original code.